# Utilizar Ancora e atualizar a pagina com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom dia, tenho um html com varias abas, quando faço algum procedimento, preciso atualizar a página, quando volta do carregamento, preciso que volte para a aba de onde parti.

Adicionei algumas ancoras, como id das minhas abas:
    `<div id="aba1"></div>`

agora precisaria passar junto com o reload do javascript o id da minha ancora.

Estou utilizando o `location.reload()` até o momento, consigo utiliza-lo para isso?
Como posso fazer?

Comment: Podes juntar um exemplo de como esses links são feitos? podes passar uma query no url, tipo `link.html?id=aba1` e ler isso no javascript. Mas seria interessante descreveres melhor o teu problema pois pode haver lógica melhor para fazer isso.

Comment: `<a href="#fragment-2">`
`<div id="fragment-2">       <jsp:include page="casa.jsp" />
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E se você usar algo assim:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.meusite.com.br/...?aba=01";
```

ai é só você ir alterando o valor do parâmetro `aba` para saber qual a aba deve vir selecionada.

Dependendo do seu `server-side` você pode usar também do jeito padrão:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.meusite.com.br/...#aba-01";
```

Ai no servidor você deve identificar qual o `ID` selecionado e colocá-lo como ativo.

Comment: Consegui também fazendo assim:
`window.location.href = '#fragment-2';`
`window.location.reload()`
Assim ele foi para minha aba com esse id.